# Iterate over the results returned from session query in SqlAlchemy and print them in a flask template

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

How can I iterate over the results returned by session.query from a database and print them in a flask template?
I have the following code where I am able to successfully iterate over the results returned from database and print employees name outside of my flask app.
I am just not able to figure out as how to use the following code and print out the employees name in a flask template:

```
def getEmployees():
    engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://<server name>/<DB name>?driver=SQL+Server+Native+Client+11.0')
    Base = declarative_base(engine)

    class Bookmarks(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'table name'
        Employee = Column(String(50))
        __table_args__ = {'autoload':True}

    def loadSession():
        metadata = Base.metadata
        Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
        session = Session()
        return session

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        session = loadSession()
        results = Bookmarks.query.filter_by(Manager='Bob')
```

Route:

```
@app.route('/employeesName', methods=['GET')
def employeesName():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('getEmployees.html')
```

Template (getEmployees.html):

```
<h2>Results</h2>
{% for employees in results %}
{{ employees.Employee }}
{% endfor %}
```

How can I print employees name filtered by Manager = 'Bob' in the flask template?
Thank you so much!

Comment: can you add the code where you render the template in the view ?

Comment: I have modified the code I am having issues with. The issue I am having is that when I go to /employeesName, I don't see anything printed.
My apologizes but I am very new to Flask thats why I copied incorrect code earlier.

Answer (score 0):

figured this out.
I was supposed to add function name while rendering the template:

```
@app.route('/employeesName', methods=['GET')
def employeesName():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('getEmployees.html', results=getEmployees())
```